# iAd frame doesn't rotate to landscape using setAutoresizingMask on iOS8

Tags: ios, xcode, iad, autoresizingmask

I have created an iAd frame right on top of the tab bar and I am using setAutoresizingMask to keep it in the right place when rotating the screen. Here is my code in viewDidLoad:

```
iAd = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
bannerIsVisible=NO;
iAd.delegate=self;
[iAd setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
 |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
// set iAd frame
iAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 50);
[self.view addSubview:iAd];
```

This will create the banner just below the screen, so it will appear when the ad is loaded using the bannerViewDidLoadAd: delegate method and going back using the didFailToReceiveAdWithError method.

This works perfectly  on iOS 6 and iOS7. 
On iOS8 the banner appears in the right place when portrait, but when I rotate the screen to landscape, the banner appears around 10 points over the right place. Is like it doesn't take into consideration that the height of the frame is smaller when landscape.
Did something change in iOS8 about setAutoresizingMask?

Thanks